# Finding xml tags: findall vs full path name

Tags: xml, python-3.x, elementtree

This question is more related to using one method over the other (which is more pythonic, which is more robust, etc). Say I want to search for a specific tag and corresponding text, I currently search using `findall` then the tag name, like below

```
root = ET.parse(xml_file).getroot()

xmlns = {'opt' : 'http://asite.com/opt',
         're' : 'http://anothersite.com'}

angle = float(root.findall('.//opt:Angle', xmlns)[0].text)
```

Instead of using the `findall` constructor, I could just specify the path to that specific tag, but is one method generally advised over the other? 
This approach of finding still relies on the fact that the element is the first one. I also would expect that the `findall` would/could be more flexible and that of specifying a full path name. My concern is also in case the XML structure changes (in which case of course try/excepts then come into play).

Answer (score 0):

Good specification of xpath query should be both flexible and give you the best performance. Using `findall` may force the parser to load and parse the whole page to the end (at least assuming `findall` returns instead of yielding the result - and this is the detail in general you should not rely on).

Therefore, in my personal opinion using `find` is just a better engineering practice. Not that there is typically a huge difference in practice.